# Rails 4, Bootstrap Modal, Devise Forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, devise

This is another Rails 4, Devise question about getting the login/signup forms into Bootstrap modals. I've noticed so many of these questions don't get any answers. I'd really appreciate it if anyone can help me find resources that help. I have tried rails casts, blog posts (more than 50) and leaving comments on those don't inspire responses either. I will create a bounty for help when time permits. Please help.

I have a bootstrap navbar, with this code:

```
<li><%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path %></li>
<li><%= link_to "Register", new_user_registration_path %></li>
```

In the views/devise/sessions/new file I have:

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Sign up</h4>
            </div>  

            <div class="modal-body">
                <%= simple_form_for(:user, :url => user_session_path) do |f| %>
                <%= f.error_notification %>

                <div class="form-inputs">
                    <%= f.input :email, :required => true, :autofocus => true %>
                    <%= f.input :password, :required => true %>
                    <%= f.input :password_confirmation, :required => true %>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">  
                <div class="form-actions">
                    <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up" %>
                </div>

            <% end %>

            <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content
  </div>
</div> -->

<div class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Sign up</h4>
            </div>  

            <div class="modal-body">
                <%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
                <%= f.error_notification %>

                <div class="form-inputs">
                    <%= f.input :email, :required => true, :autofocus => true %>
                    <%= f.input :password, :required => true %>
                    <%= f.input :password_confirmation, :required => true %>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">  
                <div class="form-actions">
                    <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up" %>
                </div>

            <% end %>

            <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

I have an application helper which has:

```
 def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
```

Really not sure what I've done wrong. There is nothing to trigger the modal. Several other blog posts have separate js script but those aren't working either.

Please please help. Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm confused about the question.  Are you not able to get the modals to appear or are they misbehaving?

Comment: Hi ABMagil. Firstly, thank you so much for the response.  I can get the modals to appear when I put this code in my navbar partial:          <li><%= link_to "Log in", "#login", "data-toggle" => "modal" %></li>

  <li><%= link_to "Register", "#register", "data-toggle" => "modal" %></li>

  <%= render "devise/sessions/login_partial" %>
  <%= render "devise/registrations/register_partial" %> However I get invalid strategy errors on both modals. I cannot render the shared links either. I get this error: Invalid strategy some_external_strategy